# How can I scrape JSON value from key?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

gg = []

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

url = ("https://sportsbook-sm-distribution-api.nsoft.com/api/v1/events?deliveryPlatformId=3&dataFormat=%7B%22default%22:%22object%22,%22events%22:%22array%22,%22outcomes%22:%22object%22%7D&language=%7B%22default%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22events%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22sport%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22category%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22tournament%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22team%22:%22sr-Latn%22,%22market%22:%22sr-Latn%22%7D&timezone=Europe%2FBelgrade&company=%7B%7D&companyUuid=4dd61a16-9691-4277-9027-8cd05a647844&filter[sportId]=3&filter[from]={}&sort=categoryPosition,categoryName,tournamentPosition,tournamentName,startsAt&offerTemplate=WEB_OVERVIEW&shortProps=1").format(current_time)

response = requests.get(url)
matches = response.json()
print(matches) #This is my json document
```

I am trying to scrape odds from betting site. I am pretty new to python and I need some help.

Some kind of "Odd id" is stored in key "b". So basically for every match in this json file, if match contains key "b" with value 2763, i want to scrape value of key "g" and store it in my list "gg"(in key "g" value is odd that i want to scrape). But if match doesn't contains key "b" with value 2763, for that match  I want to append only one time "1.00" to list "gg".

```
for match in matches:
    mat = matches['data']['events']
    for s in range(len(mat)):
        o = mat[s]['o']
        for element in o:
            h = o[element]['h']
            for x in h:
                if h[x]['b'] == 2763:
                gg.append(h[x]['g'])
```

With this command i can scrape odds but i don't how to append "1.00" to GG if match doesn't have 'b':2763 (oddid)

Comment: what is a match in this data?

Comment: There are matches in [data][events]. Odds are stored in ['data']['events']['o']['h']. In 'h' there is like some Id and in that id there is oddid  key 'b' with value ( in my case 2763) and odd key 'g' with value i want to scrape. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i haven't verified your code but i'm assuming it works and you understand what it does. what you need is a flag. a flag is just a boolean (`True`/`False`), let's name it `has_2763`. you just have to reset it at each match start

```
for match in matches:
    mat = matches['data']['events']
    for s in range(len(mat)):
        has_2763 = False
        o = mat[s]['o']
        for element in o:
            h = o[element]['h']
            for x in h:
                if h[x]['b'] == 2763:
                    gg.append(h[x]['g'])
                    has_2763 = True
        if not has_2763:
            gg.append("1.00")
```

Comment: I tried it and there is a problem. Every match has multiple OddIds.
 Match1:{ [{"OddId":2763, "Odd":1.5}, {"OddId":2764, "Odd":2.0}, {"OddId":2765, "Odd:2.5}]}. 
Match2:{ [{"OddId":2762, "Odd":1.8}, {"OddId":2764, "Odd":2.0}, {"OddId":2765, "Odd:2.5}]}.
When i run code, in match1 it will copy odd(1.5), but in match2 there is no Oddid:2763 and it will append "1.00" three times to gg(list), because there are three different oddids. These matches are just example to show you my problem. In real data "oddid" is "b" and odd(value i want to scrap) is "g". Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i don't understand what the problem is. i just verified your code. it works: there is one b with value 2763 in each match of the data of the url you gave so it cannot append three times "1.00", unless you work with different data...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your problem. This should be the solution.

```
   json = {
        'b': 2763,
        'g': 'odd number'
    }
    
    x = 'b'
    y = 2763
    gg = []
    
    for key, value in json.items():
        if x == key and y == value:  # if finds b: 2763
            gg.append(json.get('g'))
        elif x == key and y != value:
            gg.append(1.00)
            break
```

*you can reduce the number of lines using comprehension.*

Comment: The problem is that match has multiple keys "b", but I only need to find b with value 2763. So if it finds b but value is not 2763, it will append 1.00 multiple times and i only want one time. Thanks for answer!

Comment: you can use break to exit out of the loop when the condition is met first time.

Comment: I can't use .items() because it is dict. When i try 'for key, value' i get error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)". And my json file is is a little more difficult. If you have time to try and run my script it would mean a lot to me, and if you don't, thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: update the question with the JSON file that you receive, I will check it.

Comment: I don't save file to document on pc, i use it from requests. Matches is my "file". Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the structure of your JSON, it will be difficult to answer as my loop did not consider nested JSON.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).